# How to delay requestAuthorization until after login with swiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, push-notification

Normally you ask the user permission for notifications in the appDelgate function with code like this

```swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
            // Override point for customization after application launch.
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert,.sound,.badge]) { granted, error in
                guard granted else { return }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
            }
            UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
            return true
        }
```

This is default iOS behaviour and I find it very bad to ask permission for notifications even before the user has logged in or registered
I'm looking for a solution where i can make this request in a swiftUI view in the onApprear function so i can call it after the user is logged in

Who can provide simple example that works with latest versions

Comment: You can run `requestAuthorization` wherever you want. But consider that once authorization is granted (or even denied) the user will never be prompted again.

Comment: If i call this code from within a swiftUI View it is not working
```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert,.sound,.badge]) { granted, error in
                guard granted else { return }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
            }
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad, *You can run `requestAuthorization` wherever you want* **except** in a SwiftUI View. If you want to link it to the user login run it in the login area which is certainly not in a `View` either.